# WP8 ContextMenu is showing on top of WrapPanel

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'd like to have a context menu in my app that show when tap and hold the WrapPanel item but the ContextMenu is showing on top of the WrapPanel itself.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Black">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <toolkit:WrapPanel x:Name="wpPanel" Background="Black">
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="False" x:Name="cmMenu" >
                    <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="remove" Header="remove" />
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

How do I make it show in the middle of WrapPanel item?

Note : If I removed the TitlePanel, ContextMenu is showing in the middle of the WrapPanel item.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open it in middile set top margin like this:

```
   <toolkit:WrapPanel x:Name="wpPanel" Background="Green">
                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        <toolkit:ContextMenu IsZoomEnabled="False" x:Name="cmMenu" Margin="0,50,0,0">
                            <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="remove" Header="remove"/>
                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:WrapPanel>
```

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is the ContextMenu should appear in the middle of WrapPanel item.

Comment: to to context menu in middle of wrap panel item adjust margin as per your need

Comment: you could set VirticalAlignment="Center" but that is not working as you required